# Inverse for $1-zb(z)$

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, power-series, formal-power-series

I need to find the inverse of $1-zb(z)$ with $b(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nz^n$.

I have tried several approaches where I among other things have tried using the methods in my calculus book but nothing seems to quite work.

What would be the best approach to find this inverse (and what is it)?

(I'm not necessarily asking for the full solution - just the approach and the result so I can deduce the answer myself and know that I got the right answer)

Comment: Do you mean the compositional inverse, or the reciprocal (i.e., multiplicative inverse) of the series?

Comment: It actually doesn't say which in the problem. It just states: "Write explicitly the series inverse for the series $1-zb(z)$ for any
$b(z)\in\mathbb{C}[[z]]$.

Comment: Since you can only compose formal series when their constant terms are $0$ (unless one of them is a polynomial), I suspect it's supposed to be the multiplicative inverse.  This also makes sense because, as you stated in another of your questions, a formal series over a field has a reciprocal iff the constant term is nonzero, and here it is $1$.  In any case, the exercise is phrased ambiguously.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of the questions I am working on right now are phrased ambiguously... It is hard enough solving them without having to deciffer their meaning first :P

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where $b_1 = 1$ and $b_j = 0$ for all other $j$. Then your function is $f(z) = 1 - z^2$. Since $f(1) = f(-1) = 0$, this function doesn't have an inverse.

Since the problem of finding the inverse cannot be solved for this specific case, it also can't be solved for the general case. You're going to need to tell us more about the coefficients for us to be of any use.

Comment: It only says that $b_n\in\mathbb{C}$ and that I am working with the ring $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ of formal power series in the problem and that I should explicitely write out the inverse

Comment: Sigh. So you didn't really know what you wanted when you posted this problem. From the comments above, it looks as if you want the multiplicative inverse rather than the compositional. Do you know the formula for $\frac{1}{1-u}$? You could simply apply that, and then simplify.

Comment: I haven't heard about there being two different inverses - I only know one...
I tried doing exactly that as the first thing but I didn't work out

Comment: I have tried another approach: $1-zb(z)=\frac{1}{1-0}-zb(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(0^n-b_n(z)z^{n+1})$. Then the inverse is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ with $a_n=-\frac{1}{b_0}\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_ja_{n-j}$ and $a_0=\frac{1}{1-zb_0}$. Is this correct?